Using useEffect takes time to load and not using it leads to render the component twice
I have been working on password generator and I want a feature that generates the initial password when the user opens the site.
This takes time to load lets say 1-2 seconds.
const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");
useEffect(() => {
    setPassword(generatePassword(current));
}, []);


This renders the password twice...
const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>(generatePassword());

I am passing it in a input box.
<input type="text" disabled value={password} readOnly />


Can you please share the generatePassword() method implemention, there is a high possibility that method taking time.

"I want a feature that generates the initial password when the user opens the site" then you don't need to put it inside the react render cycle at all. Just have it be a top-level call in the file: const passwd = generatePassword(); export const MyComponent = (props) => { ... } since you calculate it once and it never changes.

@SurendraSinghAswal I don't know if this is right way to share since I am new here. but my implementation is here... code

Please always add code in question as text don't show code as image, also you can update your question to add or remove content after its submitted. Use images to show current & expected output or any case which can't be explained in words.

@Prabesh Shrestha add the full code from image, in the above question.

Have you tried useLayOutEffect. You should give it a try because useLayOutEffect runs even before the initial render. You can check useLayOutEffect's complete documentation from react official docs
